# multiple filepaths in S3KeySensor on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have some tasks that need to be run when one of few certain files or directories changes on S3.

Let's say I have PythonOperator, and it needs to run if /path/file.csv changes or if /path/nested_path/some_other_file.csv changes.

I have tried to create dynamic KeySensors like this:

```
    trigger_path_list = ['/path/file.csv', '//path/nested_path/some_other_file.csv']
    for trigger_path in trigger_path_list:
        file_sensor_task = S3KeySensor(
                    task_id=get_sensor_task_name(trigger_path),
                    poke_interval=30,
                    timeout=60 * 60 * 24 * 8,
                    bucket_key=os.path.join('s3://', s3_bucket_name, trigger_path),
                    wildcard_match=True)
                file_sensor_task >> main_task
```

However, This would mean both S3KeySensors would have to be triggered in order for it to be processed. 
I have also tried to make both tasks unique like here:

```
        for trigger_path in trigger_path_list:
            main_task = PythonOperator(
task_id='{}_task_triggered_by_{}'.format(dag_name, trigger_path), 
...)
            file_sensor_task = S3KeySensor(
                task_id=get_sensor_task_name(trigger_path),
                poke_interval=30,
                timeout=60 * 60 * 24 * 8,
                bucket_key=os.path.join('s3://', s3_bucket_name, trigger_path),
                wildcard_match=True)
            file_sensor_task >> main_task
```

However, this would mean that the DAG would not finish if all of the files from the list did not appear. So if /path/file.csv appeared 2 times in a row, it would not be triggered the second time, as this part of the DAG would be completed.

Isn't there a way to pass multiple files to the S3KeySensor ? I do not want to create one DAG for every path, as for me it would be 40 DAGS x around 5 paths, which gives around 200 DAGs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ideas for this:

1. Use Airflow's other task [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules), specifically you probably want `one_success` on the main task, which means just one of however many upstream sensors need to succeed for the task to run. This does mean other sensors will still keep running, but you could potentially use [soft_fail](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base_sensor_operator/index.html?highlight=soft_fail#airflow.sensors.base_sensor_operator.BaseSensorOperator) flag with a low `poll_timeout` to avoid any failure. Alternatively, you can have the main task or a separate post-cleanup task mark the rest of the sensors in the DAG as success.
2. Depending on how many possible paths there are, if it's not too many, then maybe just have a single task sensor that loops through the paths to check for changes. As soon as one path passes the check, you can return so the sensor succeeds. Otherwise, keep polling if no path passes.

In either case, you would still have to schedule this DAG frequently/non-stop if you're looking to keep listening on new files. In general, Airflow isn't really intended for long-running processes. If the main task logic is easier to perform via Airflow, you could still consider having an external process monitor changes, but then [trigger a DAG](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/trigger-dag-operator/) via the API or CLI that contains the main task.

Also not sure if applicable here or something you considered already, but you may be interested in [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to more explicitly learn about changed files or directories, which could then be consumed by the [SQSSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/aws_sqs_sensor/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The first one looks actually really promising. For the second point, hosw would you make s3FileSensor look through all of the given paths? Is there a way to do it without editing how Sensor works itself? The last suggestion seems to have only broad bucket events, not specific ones for directories

Comment: Yeah I don't think you'd be able to do #2 without creating a custom sensor to do this. However, if you build it in top of the existing [S3KeySensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor.py) and [S3Hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.9/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py) I don't think you'll get a lot of the logic almost for free.